# MacOS wifi roaming behavior

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport, 802.1x

Help me understand MacOS roaming behavior

According to [Official sources](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206207) macOS wifi card will trigger a Roam event when -75dbm is reached.

I have couple of this on my log:

```
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.868 Driver Event: <airportd[157]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: APPLE80211_M_ROAM_START (en0)
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.868 Info: <airportd[157]> Roaming started on interface en0
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.869 Info: <airportd[157]> PRIORITY LOCK ADDED [client=airportd, type=4, interface=en0, priority=5]
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.869 Info: <airportd[157]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __setAWDLOperatingMode:interface:error:]: attempting to set AWDL mode to 2
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.870 Info: <airportd[157]> SUSPEND AWDL for interface en0, timeout=10.0s, reason=Roam, token=636
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.919 Driver Event: <airportd[157]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: APPLE80211_M_ROAM_END (en0)
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.919 Info: <airportd[157]> Roaming ended on interface en0
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.921 Driver Event: <airportd[157]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: SCAN_CACHE_UPDATED (en0)
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.923 Info: <airportd[157]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext setRoamInProgress:reason:]_block_invoke: roam status metric data: CWAWDMetricRoamStatus: status:3 security: 2 profile:3 origin:<b4fbe4>(-37) target:<b4fbe4>(-37) latency:0.051313s
```

I'm pretty sure that it triggered a roaming event but it doesn't changed the BSSID (no BSSID_CHANGED callback was triggered) so it stayed on the same AP(current bssid), the other AP usually has -80dbm from here not feasible to roam, then take a look at this line

```
Fri Aug  9 16:48:01.923 Info: <airportd[157]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext setRoamInProgress:reason:]_block_invoke: roam status metric data: CWAWDMetricRoamStatus: status:3 security: 2 profile:3 origin:<b4fbe4>(-37) target:<b4fbe4>(-37) latency:0.051313s
```

it also states that the current AP is with -37dbm which is usual and pretty much accurate.

So if the trigger is -75dbm why i have so many roaming events like this ? does it take missed beacons or some other factors ?

EDIT: i forgot to mention that both AP are on 802.11ac and 80mhz